# How to remove an entity without loading its contents?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a service with a removeById operation whose goal is to remove an entity from the repository. As I don't want to fetch the contents of the entity before it gets removed, I use getReference() instead of find() to obtain the entity.

An entity named 'MyObject' has a @ManyToOne association with an entity named 'MySource', and the fetch type is set to LAZY.
When I get a reference to an instance of 'MyObject' and I remove that instance from the DB, both 'MyObject' and 'MySource' get hydrated first before the instance is removed.

Sample code:

```
@Entity
public class MyObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private final MySource source;

    public MyObject(MySource source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    protected MyObject() {
        this.source = null;
    }

    public long id() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public MySource source() {
        return this.source;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equals = this == obj;

        if (!equals && obj instanceof MyObject) {
            MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;
            equals = other.id() == id;
        }

        return equals;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) id % 16;
    }

}


@Entity
public class MySource {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    public MySource(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected MySource() {
        this.name = "";
    }

    @Column
    private final String name;

    public long id() {
        return id;
    }

    public String name() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equals = this == obj;

        if (!equals && obj instanceof MySource) {
            MySource other = (MySource) obj;
            equals = other.id() == id;
        }

        return equals;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) id % 16;
    }

}

public void removeById(long id) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    MyObject myObjectRef = em.getReference(MyObject.class, id);
    em.remove(myObjectRef);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.clear();
}
```

When the transaction is committed, I can see the following queries:

- SELECT ID, SOURCE_ID FROM MYOBJECT WHERE (ID = ?)
- SELECT ID, NAME FROM MYSOURCE WHERE (ID = ?)
- DELETE FROM MYOBJECT WHERE (ID = ?)

And more surprisingly, if I change the fetch type from LAZY to EAGER in the 'MyObject' -> 'MySource' association, then I obtain:

- DELETE FROM MYOBJECT WHERE (ID = ?)

This time the proxies are not hydrated.

What's wrong with LAZY loading when a proxy is used to remove an entity? And why the proxies are not hydrated when the fetch type is set to EAGER?

Did I miss something, or am I facing some bug in EclipseLink?

(EclipseLink 2.6.4 + static weaving on Java 8 SE).

**Additional note**

I think that the proxies are hydrated too eagerly. For instance, a statement like this.someAssociatedEntity = other.someAssociatedEntity issues a SELECT to fetch that associated entity, despite the fact that the association is annotated with a LAZY fetch type.

I would expect that a SELECT occurs only when the fields of the associated entity are accessed.

**For debug purpose:**
Stack trace when the MySource table is deleted just before the 'MyObject' entity is removed:

```
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, NAME FROM MYSOURCE WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="source" referenceClass=MySource )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1620)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2056)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRowFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2756)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiateForUnitOfWorkValueHolder(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiateImpl(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89)
    at example.MyObject._persistence_get_source(MyObject.java)
    at example.MyObject._persistence_get_source_vh(MyObject.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.MethodAttributeAccessor.getAttributeValueFromObject(MethodAttributeAccessor.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.MethodAttributeAccessor.getAttributeValueFromObject(MethodAttributeAccessor.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.getAttributeValueFromObject(DatabaseMapping.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.getAttributeValueFromObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.earlyPreDelete(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1412)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:134)
    at test.Main.test(Main.java:203)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

Comment: JPQL Bulk Delete would do the job, but that only works if a plain SQL delete will sort out FKs

Comment: Is there a viable JPA only solution? (I don't want to bother with cascade JPQL delete in case MyObject has other associations to deal with)

Comment: JPQL Bulk Delete is a JPA only solution. I didnt say SQL (native).

Comment: Ok, but you don't answer the question I asked: when the fetch type is LAZY, both MyObject and MySource instances are hydrated before they are removed form the DB, while when the fetch type is EAGER, none of them are hydrated.

Comment: add some debugging - possibly remove the MYSOURCE table so that you get an exception from the query so it shows where it is being executed from, and post the stack.

Comment: @Chris: stack trace added to the post

Comment: Clearly I don't answer that question since I posted a COMMENT to give you a way of getting around whatever you see. An ANSWER would go BELOW for those that can ANSWER that point

Comment: If You start project, implement business / consistency rules by JPA, hard to imagine deleting without checking this rules (skipping loading objects). This is cost of JPA (but benefits too)

Comment: I have a rich domain model, where the entities are JPA annotated entities, and where the association rules between the entities are implemented in the entities (not an anemic model). Still, the trouble I have with EclipseLink is that it hydrates the proxies too eagerly, so removing an entity from the repo leads to fetching its children first...

Comment: Looks like a potential bug.  The code involved is attempting to check for the referenced object, so that it can order deletes and prevent it from being removed before the object referencing it. This needs to actually fetch the object in a number of cases, but I don't believe it necessary here. More likely a problem from some other fix had this unintended consequence that caused the _persistence_get_source_vh method to trigger indirection rather than return the proxy.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your analysis.